# Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(DiveLogTable)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider> Error in Redux component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, router

I have managed to get the below error message on a couple of components that I am not sure how I am getting. I have other files using Redux that work correctly and use the same fields and they work correctly however I am not sure what is throwing this error. All my data pulls are currently going through a Reducer that looks to be set-up correctly.

What is the usual cause of these types of errors? Other components work correctly with the store so I think the problem is on this component. My store is already wrapped in a Provider and the component is connected to the App.js file.

Why would some child classes of the App.js file work and some not when they are accessing the same data?

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(DiveLogTable)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(DiveLogTable) in connect options.
```

component giving error

```
const DiveLogTable = (props) => {

    // select user object from redux
    const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

    // get the object with all the fields
    const fields = useSelector(state => state.fields);

    // pulls the users dive log list
    const {userDiveLogList} = user;

    // can destructure individual fields
    const {regionList, diveTypeList} = fields;

    const [userDive, setUserDive] = useState({
        diveID: "",
        diveTypeID: "",
        diveSchoolNameID: "",
        diveCurrentID: "",
        diveVisibilityID: "",
        diveMaxDepth: "",
        diverUserNumber: "",
        diveVerifiedBySchool: "",
        diveNotes: "",
        diveSpotID: "",
    });

    // get access to dispatch
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        pullUserDiveLog(props.match.params.userID);
    }, [props.match.params.userID]);


    const handleExpandClick = () => {
        const {state} = this
        this.setState({...state,expanded: !state.expanded})
    };

const classes = useStyles;

    return (

   .....

function mapStateToProps(state){
    const { user } = state.auth;
    const { diveLogFields } = state.diveLogFields;
    return {
        user,
        diveLogFields,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DiveLogTable);
```

My store is set-up like the below so I have the provider wrapped already and my app.js route are wrapped in Router.

store

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <CssBaseline />
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

store

```
const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk),
        window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
    )
);

export default store;
```

****update**

**Could this be to do with me having multiple Providers wrapped? It looks like I have a Provider for Redux and React Router? Do these conflict?****

[image]

Should I be using mapStateToProps in my app.js as well? It is declaring the user store data in Redux so would this mean it stays in my app in all components and I don't have to call it in any of the components?

app.js

```
class App extends Component {


    constructor(props) {

        super(props);

        this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            showUserLevelAccess: false,
            showSchoolLevelAccess: false,
            showAdminLevelAccess: false,
            currentUser: undefined,
        };

        history.listen((location) => {
            props.dispatch(clearMessage());
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const user = this.props.user;
        console.log(user)
        if (user) {
            this.setState({
                currentUser: user,
                showUserLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 1,
                showSchoolLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 2,
                showSiteAdminLevelAccess: user.userRoles === 3,
            });
        }
    }

    logOut() {
        this.props.dispatch(logout());
    }

    render() {

        const {
            // current user gives specific user details
            currentUser,
            // levels give role access
            userLevelAccess,
            schoolLevelAccess,
            siteAdminLevelAccess,
        } = this.state;

        const classes = useStyles;

        return (

            <Router history={history}>
                <div className={classes.root}>
                {/*<Grid className="container">*/}
                    {/*<ScubaNavbar>*/}
                <AppBar position="static" className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
          .......

                    <div className="container mt-3">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={HomePage} />
                            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                            <Route exact path="/registration" component={Registration} />
                            {/*<Route exact path="/aboutsustscub" component={About} />*/}
                            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                            <Route exact path="/divelogform" component={DiveLogForm} />
                            <Route exact path="/divelogtable" component={DiveLogTable} />
                            <Route exact path="/divespotform" component={DiveSpotForm} />
                            <Route exact path="/schoollogapproval" component={ApproveDiveLog} />
                            {/*<Route exact path="/divespottable" component={diveSpotTable} />*/}
                            <Route exact path="/marinelifeform" component={MarineLifeForm} />
                            <Route exact path="/articleform" component={ArticleForm} />
                            <Route exact path="/scubamap" component={ScubaMap} />
                            <Route exact path="/schoollist" component={SchoolList} />
                            {/*<Route exact path="/imageupload" component={ImageUpload} />*/}
                            <Route path="/user" component={UserLevelAccess} />
                            <Route path="/school" component={SchoolLevelAccess} />
                            <Route path="/siteadmin" component={SiteAdminLevelAccess} />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                    <DefaultFooter />
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    const { user } = state.auth;
    return {
        user,
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Judging by the errors it seems to have come form the backend so it could be something to do with the params.userID being passed to the reducer for the data pull.

Comment: Are you sure your are importing the correct `store` object to provide into the `<Provider>` ?

Comment: @JimboGee Can you share a minimal [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io) that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Not at the minute unfortunately. I think with the Thunk applyMidleware in the store the error might be coming from there. The two components that are throwing this error are the two that I am passing params to get specific data so I may need to fix them.

Comment: It seems like you are using a Provider instance in App component too, can you show it as well

Comment: Thats it added now. Should I be calling both componentDidMount and mapStateToProps in my app.js? I only added in Redux after my authentication system. If I call something in mapStateToProps in my app.js does this get passed down to all my child components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a few months back, so here is what I can recall in regard to the solution that I found.

Before creating the store variable, create a boolean variable by the name of `composeEnhancers` as follows.

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
```

Once you have created the composeEnhancers variable, you can create the store variable. When creating the store, instead of using the `compose` method like you did above, use the `composeEnhancers` variable in its place and pass `applyMiddleware(thunk)` as a parameter.

```
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Here is the full snippet of code.

```
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```